# Existe método alternativo ao window.print()?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Desejo imprimir um iframe, mas o método print() não funciona devido meu atributo "src" conter

> "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E",

Existe um método que me permita chamar a janela de impressão do navegador?

Update:
Segue o erro:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://testeecm:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The
>   frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

meu iframe:

```
 {
     xtype      : "component",
     hidden: true,
     id         : 'iframeDudu',
     items:[
         //framedudu
     ],

  autoEl     : {
    width : 1000,
    //hidden: true,
    height: 700,
    tag   : "iframe",
    //items: myPanel
    id:'frameAutoEl',
    //src   : "http://testeecm:8080/webdesk"

    //src   : "http://servidorweb/redmine/login?back_url=http%3A%2F%2Fservidorweb%2Fredmine%2F"
    //Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://testeecm:8080" from accessing a
    // frame with origin "http://servidorweb". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

    //html           : '<iframe src="http://forum.extjs.com.br/index.php?/topic/27562-resolvido-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-exibindo-arquivo-pdf-na-window-do-extjs/?hl=imprimir"></iframe>',

    //html : thtml  //acontece nada

    //src : 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(thtml)
    src : "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3Efoo%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E",
    // Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://testeecm:8080" from accessing a frame
    // with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http",
    // the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

     }// final autoElement


}
```

Comment: "mas o método print() não funciona" - como assim? podes dar um exemplo no jsFiddle ou aqui?

Comment: ele retorna uma página em branco pra você? Pois para imprimir o frame você tem que configura-lo do lado do servidor

Comment: Ele não imprime, o erro ocorre no console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontrei outro método que imprimisse um iframe.
A alternativa foi criar uma `window` e passar o conteúdo html para ela.
Usei a biblioteca Handlebars para passar os dados para o html da janela.
Assim, eu não preciso imprimir o iframe, nem preciso da propriedade `src` do iframe.
Apenas imprimo a `window` com o conteúdo `html` já incorporado anteriormente:

```
var imprimirAso = function (){
source = '<button id="imprimir" onclick="divPrint()">Imprimir</button>' +
'<table>' +
'<tr>' +
'<td style="width:100px">' +
'<img class="logo"/>' +
'</td>' +
'</td>' +
'<td><strong>Empresa:</strong> {{razaoSocial}}</td>' +
'<td><strong>CNPJ:</strong>    {{cnpj}}</td>' +
'</td>'',

var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "razaoSocial": razaoSocial, "cnpj": cnpj, "endereco": endereco, "cidade": cidade, "estado": estado,
"fantasiaClinica"       : fantasiaClinica, "enderecoClinica": enderecoClinica, "bairroClinica": bairroClinica,
"cidadeClinica"         : cidadeClinica, "ufClinica": ufClinica, "cepClinica": cepClinica, "telefoneClinica": '',
"nomeCandidato"         : Ext.getCmp('nome').getValue(), "descSetor": Ext.getCmp('descSetor').getValue(),
"dataNascimento"        : Ext.get('dataNascimento').dom.value, "cpf": Ext.getCmp('cpf').getValue(),
"funcao"                : Ext.getCmp('funcao').getValue(),
"example"               : "<button> Hello </button>"
},

var result = template(data);
wnd = window.open('', '', 'width=1000,height=850');
wnd.document.write(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente essa solução:

```
window.frames["printf"].focus();
window.frames["printf"].print();
```

Mas com o código fonte fica mais facil identificar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa:

### JS

```
function printFrameContent(id) {
    var cFrame = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow;
    cFrame.focus();
    cFrame.print();
    return false;
}
```

### HTML

```
<iframe id="conteudo" src=""></iframe>

<button onclick="printFrameContent('conteudo')"> Teste de Impressão </button>
```